# How do you use gulp-angular-templatecache with gulp-usemin

Tags: angularjs, templates, gulp, gulp-usemin

I want to add the templates as a JS cache in the same way you add your js using use-min. The problem is that use-min doesn't allow to add arbitrary content in the use-min steps out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The html:

```
<!-- build:jslib assets/js/lib.js -->
<script src="bower_components/bower-stuff/some.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js assets/js/app.js -->
<script src="assets/app/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/app/config.js"></script>
<script src="assets/app/routes.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:templateCache assets/js/templateCache.js -->
<script src="assets/app/templateCachePlaceholder.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

* (the reason for the placeholder is that it seems like use-min reads the input files and not the output files to determine type)

The gulp task:

```
gulp.task('build', ['bower', 'compass'], function () {
    return gulp.src(
        [
            'frontend-src/index.html',
            'frontend-src/config/**/*',
            'frontend-src/assets/img/**/*',
            'frontend-src/assets/fonts/**/*',
            'frontend-src/assets/translations/*'
        ],
        {base: 'frontend-src/'})
        .pipe(plugins.if(isIndexHtml, plugins.usemin({
            js: [plugins.ngAnnotate(), plugins.uglify(), plugins.rev()],
            jslib: [plugins.rev()],
            css: [plugins.minifyCss(), 'concat', plugins.rev()],
            templateCache: [
                plugins.addSrc('frontend-src/assets/app/**/*.html'),
                plugins.angularTemplatecache({
                    module: ANGULARJS_MODULE_NAME,
                    root: 'assets/app/'
                }),
                'concat',
                plugins.rev()
            ]
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend-prod/'));

    function isIndexHtml (file) {
        return file.path.match('index\\.html$');
    }
});
```

Comment: would it be possible to know the exact version of usemin and templatecache which you used ? (I'm having some problems to reproduce your solution). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @user2038596 I don't work at the company that I did this in so I don't have access to the soruce anymore. But the use-min version at least was probably somewhere around 0.3.8. Let me know if you're still stuck and I'll see if I can replecate it when I get back from vacation.